# create a port forwarding through ssh-tunnel in .ssh/config

Tags: linux, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am actually scratching my head about this one.

I found this excellent guide for for [port-forwarding via multiple ssh-hops](http://rubenlaguna.com/blog/2014/06/10/ssh-port-forwarding-through-multiple-hops-slash-dot-ssh-slash-config-slash/).

Folowing this guide I tried this:

This works:

```
$ ssh -t hop -L 9080:localhost:9080 \
> ssh -A -t user@192.168.1.100 -L 9080:localhost:9080
```

with .ssh/config

```
Host hop
    User extUser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.company.pub
    Hostname company.com
    ForwardAgent yes
    Port 11000
```

This actually opens a port on my machine via hop to the 100 target machine's service at port 9080.

The hop server has access to 192.168.1.100:9080 (i.e. `wget 192.168.1.100:9080` succeeds)

So according to the guide, this should work as well:

```
ssh -L 9080:192.168.1.100:9080 hop
```

But it does not. It opens the connection to the hop ssh point (-f -N) would prevent this) but the tunnel is not forwarded to the destination. What am I missing?

Of course finally it should be all in the .ssh/config:

```
Host tunneled-9080
    User extUser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.company.pub
    Hostname company.com
    ForwardAgent yes
    Port 11000
    LocalForward 9080 192.168.1.100:9080
```

so a simple

```
ssh -f -N tunneled-9080
```

is all I need.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: So where would it be on-topic then, @Martin ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Can someone move this then to http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: [su] would be more appropriate, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, if someone comes to this question.

Everything above is correct and works. What tricked me, was my way too clever browser which converted sometime through the trying out `localhost:9080` into `www.localhost.com:9080` which of course failed horribly. *dough*

Stupid clever firefox

Answer (score 0):

The first command (combined with the `ssh config`) is logging into `hop` as user `extUser` and from there logging into the `100` machine as user `user`.

While the second command tries to log into both machines as user `extUser`. This is probably why it fails - because user `extUser` does not have access setup on the `100` machine.

Comment: actually the second command is not logging in to the 100-machine at all. It just directs the end of the tunnel to the 100:9080. So yes, it skips one ssh login. What should be working fine, as 192.168.1.100:9080 is visible from my hop machine. ?

Comment: What I meant was that it tries to get into the `100` machine as the user `extUser` - because that's what happens when you do not specify the user on the command line or in config - it uses the current logged in user. Try passing the `-v` option to both the `ssh` commands in the first command to see what it is really doing.

Comment: Oh, and, no, it is not "skipping" the second login. It *is* trying to get into the `100` machine as `extUser`. It will try to find the allowed keys for `extUser` on `100`.